# Objective-c Parse JSON Response

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have been doing a lot of reading but I have not been able to find anything close to what I am trying to do.  I am getting a JSON response and populating a `UITableView` with the results.  When the user selects the row on the `UITableView` I want to grab the corresponding "id" value that is associated with the name displayed.  Example JSON response:

```
{"active":true,"created_at":"2012-05-12T03:04:21Z","description":"Test 1",
"id":11,"name":"This Is A Test","updated_at":"2012-05-12T03:04:21Z"}
```

So I set the `UITableView` row with a name of This Is A Test and when the user selects that I want to return the number 11 as being selected.  In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function I can pull the

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

sc.selectedCategory = cellText;
```

Which will give me the name of the object but how can I call the dictionary again and get the value of "id" where the name matches the selected cell?  I am pretty new to objective-c but have been doing java for years.  Any examples would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a dictionary. You need to cast the Array `objectAtIndex` (tableview index path) as an `NSDictionary` object and then use `valueForKey`.

Something like the following in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSDictionary *selRow = (NSDictionary *)[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSInteger myID = [[selRow valueForKey@"id"] intValue];
```

Comment: Since I already had my objects divided up into arrays I was able to just get the value using [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].... This seems to be working without going back to the json dictionary object.